# compare nodeJS objects using wildcards

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for a way to compare two objects in a more flexible way.
I would want something like this:

```
var alice = {
                firstname:'Jan',
                lastname:'Smith',
                amount: 0,
                friendList:[], 
                removeAmount : function(amount){
                    this.amount = this.amount - amount;
                }
    };
```

should match this

```
var aliceWildCard = {
            firstname: 'Jan',
            lastname:*,
            *,
            removeAmount : function(amount){
                this.amount = this.amount - amount;
            }
};
```

The * after the properties, mean that the property has to be there but the value is not important.
Note that the * after "lastname:*," means I allow additional properties to be declared.

Are there any modules that exist that allow me to do this? I tried to google it but I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is using some JSON schema to validate your object agains. You can do it with a couple of nodejs modules like [schema-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/schema-validator)

Here is the example on how you might implement that with schema-validator (Note that this is not all of the functionality that you wanted, but I believe you can think of something):

```
var Validator = require('schema-validator');

var aliceSchema = {
    type: Object,

    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        test: /^Jan$/i
    },

    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    removeAmount: {
        type: Function,
        required: true
    }
}


var aliceValidator = new Validator(aliceSchema);
aliceValidator.debug = true;

var result = aliceValidator.check({
    firstname: 'Jan',
    lastname: 'Smith',
    removeAmount: function() { }
});

console.log(result);
```

The problem with your code-snippet is that your aliceWildcard object can't even be parsed by Javascript because of that wildcard notation. You will probably have to search for another way to validate your object's contents (like schema-validator).